# Symbol of precision and precision matrix

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-process

*This is one of my first questions so sorry in advance for any rules that I break.*

Is there any mainstream convention for the symbol of the precision and precision matrix?

I have seen the following ones:

- In *Information theory, inference and learning algorithms* by MacKay:

$$ \text{Precision: }\tau = 1 / \sigma^2$$
$$ \text{Precision matrix: }\mathbf{A} = \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} $$

- In *Pattern recognition and machine learning* by Bishop:

$$ \text{Precision: }\beta = 1 / \sigma^2$$
$$ \text{Precision matrix: }\boldsymbol{\Lambda} = \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} $$

Is any of them preferred over the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change a lot but in the Gaussian Process literature, it's usually $K$ (for kernel matrix) or $\Sigma$. Precision matrices also change a lot but as you say $A$ and $\Lambda$ are pretty common. As long as you clearly introduce the term though you can use whichever convention you want.